# Error importing gradle project Eclipse: Target not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, gradle

I am trying to import ckChangeLog as a gradle project in Eclipse. I have Eclipse Mars and build tool 23.0.1
Android API is installed and is clearly available for other projects.
Following is the error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\ckChangeLog-master (2)\ckChangeLog-

master\android-mvn-push.gradle' line: 57

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':ckChangeLog'.

  > failed to find target android-21 : C:\Android SDK ADT Bundle - Windows 64 Bits
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

A prompt support will be appreciated I have searched over the web but no solutions seems to work so far

Comment: I guess you need to install  android sdk 21

Comment: I would encourage you ro use Android Studio which is built on top of Intellij IDEA. Android development works smoothly and have done the switch from eclipse to idea and i like every bit of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might not have the **Android-21 sdk** installed. You need to install ***android sdk 21*** .

**Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if API 21** is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding directory ending with ../sdk
Like
 C:\Android SDK ADT Bundle - Windows 64 Bits\sdk